# Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'

Tags: xetex

I noted there are some similar questions for my problem on this list, but none of them solve my issue.

So I post it here again:

Hi,

I try to compile LaTeX thesis use the following steps:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.kwant-project.org/jbweston/thesis.git thesis.git
$ cd thesis.git
$ make
[...]
! Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'.

See the mathspec package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                             

l.54 \RequirePackage{amsmath}

? No pages of output.
Transcript written on build/thesis.log.
make: *** [Makefile:14: thesis.pdf] Error 1
```

Any hints for solving this issue?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Load the package earlier than mathspec.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If @Johannes_B's suggestion does not work then please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing: without code that exhibits your problem we have to guess what you are doing. If you just give an error message it is almost impossible to help. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command then contain the *smallest* amount of code necessary to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well help identify the problem. If not post it here.

Comment: (And a url does not count as a MWE.  We need the code here, not elsewhere.)

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to load both mathspec and unicode-math.  use one or the other

Comment: Note you should have edited this question rather than post a new one (but it's OK you can simply delete this now)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, it does the trick.