# Repost it with a minimal working example for the amsmath must be loaded earlier than mathspec problem

Tags: xetex

See the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  1 + 2 = 3 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Run the above code with xelatex will meet the following error:

```
! Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'.

See the mathspec package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.54 \RequirePackage{amsmath}

?
```

$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019)

Regards

Comment: You should not load both `mathspec` and `unicode-math`. They fight each other.

Comment: @egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533194/package-mathspec-error-amsmath-must-be-loaded-earlier-than-mathspec#comment1348403_533194

Answer (score 3):

The `mathspec` package uses a hand-made test to suggest `amsmath` being loaded before it: precisely, it redefines `\RequirePackage`, which is quite a bad thing to do.

The redefinition is not really dangerous in itself, but it's rather naïve: the redefined command just checks whether the mandatory argument to `\RequirePackage` is `amsmath` and, in this case, it emits the error message.

It happens that recent versions of `unicode-math` indeed do `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`, so the error is triggered.

However, this is a false problem: `mathspec` and `unicode-math` are very unfriendly to each other, because they want to do the same thing, namely, to take control of math typesetting.

I don't think there is any way to make them to cooperate. Load either one or the other, not both.